# How to make variable visible outside fs.readFile callback function

Tags: javascript, scope, gulp, fs, readfile

I have a following task in my gulpfile.js:

```
function compileHandlebars() {
    options = {
        batch: ['./src/views/modules/*.hbs']
    }

    let data;
    
    fs.readFile('./data.json', 'utf-8', (error, content) => {
        if(error) throw error;
        data = content;
        console.log(data) // --> outputs actual content
    });

    console.log(data); // --> outputs undefined

    return gulp.src('./src/views/layouts/index.hbs')
        .pipe(handlebars(data)) // <-- receives 'undefined' as an argument
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    };
```

It is supposed to load data.json content and assign it to a variable called 'data', so that it can be used in handlebars() function in the pipeline to form html from the template. The problem is that the console.log() outputs 'undefined' as soon as i move it out of the fs.readFile() callback scope. How can I make the 'data' variable maintain the value that I set in the callback function?

Comment: The callback hasnt had a chance to finish before you call console.log. Try using fs promise and awaiting or maybe readfilesync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current call runs asynchronously, so it goes and does the work while your code moves onto the next line. Then when it's finished it triggers the callback. So you need to wait for that read to finish before moving on.

Try using `readFileSync`.

```
// Include fs module
const fs = require('fs');
  
// Calling the readFileSync() method
// to read 'input.txt' file
const data = fs.readFileSync('./input.txt', {encoding:'utf8'});
 
// Display the file data
console.log(data);
```

Comment: This seems to work, but there's one more problem on the way. The purpose of this task is to be called not only on initialization, but also on every 'data.json' change via gulp.watch task. Everything works smoothly once the page loads, then I make a change in 'data.json' file and everything recompiles and reloads as it should. However, after the second change in 'data.json' I get the following error in the console: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at FSWatcher.compileHandlebars (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\base repo\base-repo\gulpfile.js:19:21)

Comment: You could also try moving your return and console log inside of the callback. Then you'll need to put a return in front of the `fs.readFile`. Not sure about how this function works though so that might not work.

Comment: I have checked this, and it seems that fs.readFileSync() returns nothing after the second change in the json file...

Comment: I believe that `readFile` will only read the file once too. I'm not familiar with Gulp and what it is helping with but maybe you are after `watchFile` to check when files change. `fs.watchFile(logFile, (curr, prev) => {console.log(logFile + " file Changed")});`